# How to remove string from an integer in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to remove "year" after an integer in a dataframe. How can I keep the integers but remove years?
I tried the following:

```
df['Years in current job'] = lambda x: x.df['Years in current job'][0]
```

[image]

Comment: ``df['Years in current job].str[0]`` ?

Comment: Can you show some example data.

Comment: `df['Years in current job].str.split().str[0]`

Comment: But the dtype is object, so I can't use str